# WebRTC: Can't set local description after creating an answer

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, signals, webrtc

I'm currently attempting to create a simple video chat service using WebRTC with Ajax for the signalling method.

As per [the recommendation of another Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161287/webrtc-video-chat-with-ajax-instead-of-websocket-possible?answertab=votes#tab-top), in order to make sure I was understanding the flow of a standard WebRTC app properly, I first created a simple WebRTC video chat service in which I printed the created offer or answer and ICE candidates out to the screen, and manually copied and pasted that info into a text area in the other client window to process everything. Upon doing that, I was able to successfully get both videos to pop up.

After getting that to work properly, I decided to try and use Ajax as the signalling method. However, I can't seem to get it to work now.

In my current implementation, every time offer/answer or ICE candidate info is created, I instantly create a new Ajax object, which is used to add that info (after the JSON.stringify method has been executed on it) to a DB table. Both clients are constantly polling that DB table, searching for new info from the other client.

I've been echoing a lot of information out to the console, and as far as I can tell, a valid offer is always sent from one client to another, but upon receiving that offer, successfully setting it as the remote description, and creating an answer, any attempts I make to set the local description of the "answerer" fails.

Is there any particular reason why this might happen? Here's a snippet of my code:

```
var i,
  len;

for (i = 0, len = responseData.length; i < len; i += 1) {

  message = JSON.parse(responseData[i]);

  if (message.type === 'offer') {

    makeAnswer(message);

  }

  // Code omitted,

}

...

makeAnswer = function (offer) {

  pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer), function () {

    pc.createAnswer(function (desc) {

      // An answer is always properly generated here.

      pc.setLocalDescription(desc, function () {

        // This success callback function is never executed.

        setPayload(JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription));

      }, function () {

        // I always end up here.

      });

    });

  });

};
```

In essence, I loop through any data retrieved from the DB (sometimes there's both an offer and lots of candidate info that's gathered all at once), and if the type property of a message is 'offer', I call the makeAnswer function, and from there, I set the remote description to the received offer, create an answer, and try to set the answer to the local description, but it always fails at that last step.

If anyone can offer any advice as to why this might be happening, I would be very appreciative.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You are using the exact same form manually and the stream starts flowing? You don't see any JS error in the console? `pc` is already set?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, eepp. There are no errors in the console and pc is already set. The only thing that happens is the callback function for the fail condition of the setRemoteDescription method is always called (and I'm assuming the remote description is not set). When I receive the offer, I can set the remote description fine and create an answer, but when I send the answer back to the client that sent the offer, and try to set the answer for the remote description on that client, I always get the "error". Also, what do you mean by "You are using the exact same form manually ..."?

Comment: The puzzlement continues. I set my video chat service up so that when an offer/answer is created, it's both output to a textarea on the local client and it's sent to the DB, from which it's then output to the same textarea on the other client via XHR. When I try to process the offer/answer received from the server, it sometimes fails and sometimes doesn't. However, when I manually copy and paste the offer/answer output locally into the remote client textarea, then everything is always processed properly and the remote video pops up. I compared the two versions of the offer/answer...

Comment: ...line-by-line and character-by-character, and I could not find a single difference between them. What could possibly account for this discrepancy? Why would one always work and one sometimes work? I compared the offer/answer strings several times (both when both succeeded and when one succeeded but not the other), and in all cases I checked, the strings matched perfectly. What is happening here?!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out the problem. It turns out that I wasn't encoding the SDP and ICE info before sending it to a PHP script via Ajax. As a result, any plus signs (+) in the SDP/ICE info were being turned into spaces, thus causing the strings to differ between the local and remote clients and not work.

I've always used encodeURIComponent on GET requests with Ajax, but I never knew you had to use that function with POST requests as well. That's good to know.

Anyway, after I started using the encodeURIComponent function with the posted data, and then fixed my logic up a bit so that ICE candidates are never set until after both local and remote descriptions are set, it started working like a charm every time.

That's the good news. The bad news is that everything was working fine on my local host, but as soon as I ported the exact same code over to my web-hosted server, even though the console was reporting that the offer/answer and ICE info were all properly being received and set, the remote video isn't popping up.

Sigh. One more hurdle to cross before I can be done with this.

Anyway, just to let everyone know, the key is to use encodeURIComponent before sending the SDP/ICE info to a server-side script, so that the string received on the other end is exactly the same.

Comment: If you're using jQuery's `$.post`, you don't need any pre-encoding. Just send an object like `{msg: 'ice', ice: <your ICE object here>}` and jQuery will do the encoding/field splitting for you. For server to client communication, use PHP's `json_encode` and jQuery `$.get` should give you a JS object as data (it does JSON parsing automatically). About the RTC not working outside the LAN, you will probably need to include a STUN server address (when creating the PC) to traverse NATs. Even this won't be enough with some NATs; you will need a TURN server address.

Comment: eepp, yeah, I know that jQuery will handle that for me, but after I discovered the encodeURIComponent mishap, I don't think that using vanilla JS is causing me problems anymore. You might be right about the STUN/TURN thing, but what's getting me is that I put my original video chat test service up on my hosted server where I manually copied and pasted everything from and to textareas, and it works fine on my hosted server. As such, I don't think that the STUN/TURN thing is an issue. I'll keep looking into it and see if I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Eureka! I finally found the answer. It turns out that with my Ajax-signalling code running on my server, an offer/answer was being set before an attempt was being made to send the local stream to the remote peer via the addStream method. The accepted answer to the following SO question finally clued me in on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794305/i-am-not-able-to-receive-remote-video-stream. Once I moved the function that gets the offer/answer ball rolling to within the getUserMedia callback, everything worked like a charm. I'm so happy I got it working, but with that said...

Comment: It would be real nice if this were all better documented. I realized through this whole ordeal that the timing/order of all the discrete steps and events is very important (and sometimes unintuitive). As such, it would be nice if the great minds behind this technology would better document everything as even the slightest deviation results in no video at all, which is very frustrating and hard to debug. Anyway, if no one else does sometime soon, I'm going to write up an in-depth tutorial on how to do all this, 'cause current documentation is greatly lacking. Anyway, thanks again!