# Web RTC - One to One call,no error but, no remote video streaming

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento

Am using Kurento Media server for the one to one call.

In browser the call happens with no issues.

But I want to implement this in android.

Am using this, https://github.com/MaxMaes/WebRTCTest

Since, it is stated, the project is not complete, Am trying to complete this.

Am following all the steps of WebRTC.

Am able to connect to kurento one-one call app, running in server. The flow goes like this

1. Party A created in browser.
2. Party B created in android app.
3. A makes a call to B.
4. Now, on receiving "incoming call" message, the call is accepted.
5. pc.createOffer is called.
6. onCreateSuccess, pc.setLocalDescription is done.  sdpoffer is sent to B.
7. parallelly, receiving "onIceCandidate", pc.addIceCanditate is done.
8. ICEGatheringState = Complete
9. A receives the, callResponse, and sends "startcommunication"with sdpAnswer.
10. pc.setRemoteDescription, from sdpAnswer is done.
11. onAddStream called. A remote renderer is added to the UI.
12. But no streaming is coming.
13. From A, B is receiving "iceCandidate". is anything to be done on this?

In both sides, I dont get the remote video But able to see local video

And I dont get any error.

Answer (score 0):

In onAddRemoteStream change

VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender, REMOTE_X, REMOTE_Y,   REMOTE_WIDTH,REMOTE_HEIGHT, scalingType)

add one more parameter after scalingType

VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender,
 REMOTE_X, REMOTE_Y,   REMOTE_WIDTH,REMOTE_HEIGHT, scalingType,true)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried this, with updating the libjingle library. But no improvement even then. Same. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @sowmiyaksr have you find a solution?

Comment: @richa shah : I started using "openvidu" library. Openvidu is built on top of "Kurento". And it went smoothly after that. Thanks

Comment: okay is it easy to convert VideoRendererGui to openvidu? cause I got more trouble when i tried  VideoRendererGui opengl to surefece render?

Answer (score 0):

you have it like this?

`onAddRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream){
    remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remoteRender));
}`

Comment: yes.  `@Override
    public void onAddRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream) {  
        remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remoteRender));  
        VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender,
                REMOTE_X, REMOTE_Y,
                REMOTE_WIDTH, REMOTE_HEIGHT, scalingType);  
        VideoRendererGui.update(localRender,
                LOCAL_X_CONNECTED, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTED,
                LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTED, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTED,
                scalingType);
    }`

Comment: when you create the peer on android you've linked the localMediaStream to peer connection? PS. make sure you've linked the mediastream BEFORE creating the offer.

`this.pc = factory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, sdpMediaConstraints, this);
this.pc.addStream(localMediaStream);`

So the `@Override
        public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream){
mListner.onAddRemoteStream(mediaStream);
}
` is called. Then if you have videotracks. just run the lines you have above, they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In some case you can not receive video if not sending video.

Workarounded with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883182/571410